# How to change the amazon Ec2 instance keypair with the new key pair

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an instance where my site was running. But when I have restarted the instance the site went down and also I have lost my pem key which is associated to instance.

Now I am not able to access the instance.

How can I change the key pair of instance by newly added key pair on EC2 instance?

Comment: @ceejayoz - it's not really a duplicate if it's on another site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've lost the `pem` you can't. You have to replace the instance with one that uses a new key pair.

If you still have the `pem` you can generate a new key pair using `ssh-keygen` on your local box. Add the public key to the EC2 instance's `authorized_keys` file just as if it were a physical box.

Comment: I have lost the key pair by which I have created the instance and I also have the site running on that instance. I don't want to loose the data from the server.

Comment: Is there any thing we can do to replace the `pem` key

Comment: Nope. Amazon doesn't keep a copy of the private key, and they can't get into the image through any back doors. I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but that's the way it is.

Comment: Thanks @bahamat for the information. I have resolved this issue via replacing the instance by creating new instance which uses the new key pair. Thanks for the help.